# KDE: Don't start login screen before my app script finishes

Tags: linux, fedora, login, kde

I have Fedora 23 on my machine and I'm using KDE Plasma. I've written a small app which is executed before the KDE login screen appears. This was done by placing the line `/path/to/MyApp` to `/etc/sddm/Xsetup`. The app starts as expected before the login and using the `top` command I see also that `MyApp` and `Xsetup` are running. At this point also `sddm` is running but neither `sddm-greeter` nor `sddm-helper`. However, after approx. 20 seconds the login screen appears and my app is not visible anmore. In the processes I see now that `sddm-greeter` and `sddm-helper` are running now and that `Xsetup` was terminated. `MyApp` however is still under the `top` command, but not visible anymore.

Does somebody know how to prevent the greeter and helper to start as long my app is running, and only appear after the user has closed my application?

Comment: Varie, Varie, redde mihi legiones meas!

Answer (score 0):

I've done the following: Since it was obviously the `sddm` which started the `sddm-greeter` and `sddm-helper`, I've paused it as long as `MyApp` is running. The `/ets/sddm/Xsetup` file has now the following lines:

```
pkill -STOP sddm
/path/to/MyApp
pkill -CONT sddm
```

Is maybe a dirty solution, but it does the job.